# Interact with QT window from native iOS App

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, qt

I have a module created using QT creator. I have not much knowledge in QT with QML and C++. Please do let me know is there any way to open a QT Created window from our native iOS app on any button tap. I have successfully generate Xcode project from QT but my only concern is there any way to directly open QT window from native iOS app.
Please help.

Comment: If your application is running a `QApplication`, you should be able to open your Qt window. But we don't have enough information about what you are trying to achieve. For example, is the Qt window supposed to be opened in the same application or in a separate one ? Is it supposed to interact with your application or not ? etc... By the way, Qt Creator is **just an IDE**, nothing more.

Comment: I believe its a QguiApplication. i wanted to open qt window within my native iOS app in any viewcontroller. Let say i have a button "Open QT" and press on that button qt launched within the app. is it possible?